# what's the replacement HDWalletProvider in client-browser?

Tags: signature

so this `provider: new HDWalletProvider(privateKey, config.child.rpc)`
cannot be used in client browser because I need to replace that with a signature provider, I haven't success.

for init contract I usually replace it with hooks by:

```js
const { account, chainId, library } = useWeb3React()

library?.getSigner(account)
```

then I'm able to use in my contract.
but now i'm struggling to use matic.js, i have no idea how to properly use it on client-browser because matic.js only give example using node.js with HDWallet/direct private-key.

so after I initialize matic.js

```js
const posClient = async () => {
    const posClientx = new POSClient()

    return posClientx.init({
      network: "testnet",
      version: "mumbai",

      log: true,
      child: {
        provider: library?.getSigner(account),
        defaultConfig: {
          from: account,
        },
      },
      parent: {
        provider: library?.getSigner(account),
        defaultConfig: {
          from: account,
        },
      },
    })
  }
```

then call it

```
  const client = await posClient()
      console.log(client, "client")
      const erc721Token = client.erc721(
        "0x94f1e509eb86201313557463d0d7a1f8f9d2d2fa",
        true
      )
      console.log(erc721Token, "erc721Token")

      const result = await erc721Token.approveAll()

      const txHash = await result.getTransactionHash()
      console.log("txHash", txHash)
      const receipt = await result.getReceipt()
      console.log("receipt", receipt)
```

I'm not able to receive pop up metamask, if it's on node.js (using private-key) will do transaction right away, please enlight me what do i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `window.ethereum` as a provider

```
  // provider that is selected in metamask
  // for transfer, switch to polygon network
  var mainProvider = new Web3(window.ethereum);
  var maticProvider = new Web3(window.ethereum);

  parent: {
     provider: mainProvider,
     defaultConfig: {
         from: currentAccount
     }
  },
  child: {
      provider: maticProvider,
      defaultConfig: {
          from: currentAccount
      }
  }
```